# Does the registartion point change when I rotate movie clip AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a movie clip as you can see from the following link :  http://prntscr.com/2pta2j  .The registration point of it is in A, i.e. + symbol. I want to know where will be the registration point after  I rotate it 90 degree . Final view of it will be like : http://prntscr.com/2ptans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The registration point stays next to A.

**EDIT**

One exception being, if the registration point next to A is the registration point of a container that the square is in and you rotate the square within the container, not the container.